# RecyclerView: Reloading the data without blocking the UI thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app that scans your phone for MP3 and then puts them all into a list, handled by a `recyclerview` for you to scroll through them and play them.

I managed to get all of that to work before I had the `recyclerview`, but the loading of the many songs (on my phone 700+) took about 30 seconds each time, the app was open. That is ofcourse unacceptable. So now everything is being controlled by a `recyclerview`, but I don't know how to fill the reload adapter so that it doesn't reload all at once but step by step. This is what it looks ATM:

The reload adapter:

```
public class MySimpleItemLoader
{
    public List<MP3object> mP3Objects { get; private set; }
    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageValue { get; set; }
    public bool CanLoadMoreItems { get; private set; }

    public MySimpleItemLoader(List<MP3object> mp3)
    {
        this.mP3Objects = mp3;
    }

    public void LoadMoreItems(int itemsPerPage)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        for (int i = CurrentPageValue; i < CurrentPageValue + itemsPerPage; i++)
        {
            mP3Objects.Add(new MP3object() { AlbumName = string.Format("This is item {0:0000}", i) });
        }

        CanLoadMoreItems = true;
        CurrentPageValue = mP3Objects.Count;
        IsBusy = false;
    }


}
```

My Main Activity, where I load a list with all the mp3 (taking to long):

```
    private void PopulateMP3List(List<string> content)
    {
       mp3 = new List<MP3object>();        
       foreach (string obj in content)
       {
           WriteMetaDataToFileList(obj);        
       }
    }



    void WriteMetaDataToFileList(string obj)
    {
        reader.SetDataSource(obj);

        //Write Mp3 as object to global list
        MP3object ob = new MP3object();
        {
            if(reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle) != null)
            {
                ob.SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
            }
            else
            {
                ob.SongName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
            }

            if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist) != null)
            {
                ob.ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);
            }
            else
            {
                ob.ArtistName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
            }

            if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyAlbum) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyAlbum) != null)
            {
                ob.AlbumName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyAlbum);
            }
            else
            {
                ob.AlbumName = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
            }

            if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != null)
            {
                ob.Year = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear);
            }
            else
            {
                ob.Year = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
            }

            if (reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != "" && reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear) != null)
            {
                ob.Year = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyYear);
            }
            else
            {
                ob.Year = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Unknown);
            }

            ob.Mp3Uri = obj; // can never be unknown!

            ob.DurationInSec = int.Parse(reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyDuration)) / 1000; // can never be unknown, div by 1000 to get sec not millis
        }
        mp3.Add(ob);

    }

    public List<string> ReturnPlayableMp3(bool sdCard)
    {
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        string phyle;
        string path1 = null;

        if(sdCard) // get mp3 from SD card
        {
            string baseFolderPath = "";

            try
            {
                bool getSDPath = true;

                Context context = Application.Context;
                Java.IO.File[] dirs = context.GetExternalFilesDirs(null);

                foreach (Java.IO.File folder in dirs)
                {
                    bool IsRemovable = Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageRemovable(folder);
                    bool IsEmulated = Android.OS.Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageEmulated(folder);

                    if (getSDPath ? IsRemovable && !IsEmulated : !IsRemovable && IsEmulated)
                        baseFolderPath = folder.Path;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GetBaseFolderPath caused the following exception: {0}", ex);
            }

            string xy = baseFolderPath.Remove(18); // This is result after this, but this hard coded solution could be a problem on different phones.: "/storage/05B6-2226/Android/data/Media_Player.Media_Player/files"

            path1 = xy;
            // path to SD card and MUSIC "/storage/05B6-2226/"
        }
        else // get Mp3 from internal storage
        {
                path1 = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
        }

        var mp3Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path1, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string currentFile in mp3Files)
        {
            phyle = currentFile;
            res.Add(phyle);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

How would I convert this, so that the loading happens not in the main activity, but where it is needed inside the recycler view reload adapter?

Comment: If I really understand your issue is that each time you check for update ( the reload took a lot of time, what I suggest is to paginate your list to get 10 elements by page for example and after that, you use `notifyItemRangeInserted` in your adapter to load new data

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understood the `RecyclerView` usage correctly. The `RecyclerView` has the responsibility of displaying your items on the screen and nothing more.
Any data loading inside the `RecyclerView` mostly results in laggy UIs and scrolling.

To put it right you need to load your data outside of `RecyclerView`'s adapter and then notify it to project the changes. And if you have a lot data which takes a lot of time to load you can do it in smaller steps and update the `RecyclerView` after each step. Say for example you load your 700 songs in 100 song per step.

This is some sample-pseudo-code to give you some ideas. So don't expect it to actually work.

```
val audioFiles = mutableListOf<String>()
Observable.create{ e ->
    for{
        val offset = audioFiles.size
        // load your files here
        if(audioFiles.size % 100){
            e.onNext(offset)
        }
    }
    e.onComplete()
}
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe{ offset ->
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(offset, offset+100)
}
```

Comment: Is it too much to ask you how to convert it that way? xD thank you

Comment: I wouldn't say too much, but rather unintuitive. I put some code up there. In the example I used `RxJava` to easily move the work to a background thread in order to avoid UI freeze.